# Get data between two dates with date format unkown

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
date format: init(11)
date column value: 1421382119
```

I have managed to get the dates from the table.

```
$sqllast = $Db1->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = $Db1->fetch_array($sqllast)) 
{
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', $row['create']);
echo "$date1";
}
```

Question:

I want to get values from this table using the dates interval. I am not getting idea which format shall I enter the dates.
I have tried y-m-d, d-m-y , but it did not work

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE create between '2015-01-1'  and '2015-01-30'
```

Comment: use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) -> `... WHERE create between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-1')  and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-30')`?

Comment: Please write this as answer so that i can accept it .. it has worked

Comment: It appears that column "`create`" is defined as: `create INT COMMENT 'point in time something was created, encoded as integer value seconds since 1/1/1970 UTC'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing a unix_timestamp as your value in column `create`, you will want to use MySQLs [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to covert your dates to a unix_timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE create between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-1') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-30')`?
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the column type is int, you have to convert your string dates to ints as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `create` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01')  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-30')
```